# The ad size and ad unit ID must be set before loadAd is called. when I set the banner programmatically

Tags: java, android, admob, banner

I am facing the java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ad size and ad unit ID must be set before loadAd is called. whenever I try to set Banner programmatically . in fact , I want to set the AdUnitID from the java class and not from the xml.

**here is the Activity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.test">

**SOME COMPONENTS**

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/adMobView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**here is the java class (oncreate)**

```
RelativeLayout adContainer = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.adMobView);
            AdView mAdView = new AdView(this);
            mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
            mAdView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
            adContainer.addView(mAdView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

**Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**Gradle**

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2'
}
```

Comment: why you add runtime why not in xml ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose your XML code for AdMob is not correct. Make sure to add the xmlns for AdMob in your root `<RelativeLayout>`

i.e.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" //This line
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

If you've already added the code as above then you need to create it programmatically.

In your activity java file:

```
View adContainer = findViewById(R.id.adMobView);
AdView mAdView = new AdView(context);
mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
mAdView.setAdUnitId(YOUR_BANNER_ID);
((RelativeLayout)adContainer).addView(mAdView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Use it in your XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:id="@+id/adMobView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```